# Blank Fragment in android 2.3.3 (but not 4.3) with ActionBarCompat

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, android-actionbar-compat

```
package com.example.app;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(android.R.id.content) == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(android.R.id.content, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
    }
}
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

}

When I run this code in a 4.3 emulator I get the desired "Hello world!" message. In the 2.3.3 emulator howerer I get a blank screen (ActionBar does get displayed).

Comment: could it be that `getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(android.R.id.content)` does not result `null` on 2.3.3? Is there a logcat output?

Comment: It does result in null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently this is a known bug for Android 2.3 and below. There is a filed bug for this [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=58108&can=1&q=android.R.id.content&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars).

Solution for support library versions prior to v19:

Try creating an XML layout for the `Activity` (i.e. just a `ViewGroup` like `LinearLayout` or `RelativeLayout` and give it an id). Then call `setContentView(R.layout.newLayout)` in the `Activity`'s `onCreate()`. Then use the id of the `ViewGroup` as the first parameter of `FragmentTransaction.add()`.

This issue has been resolved as of version 19 of the support library. If you update to the latest version of the support library using the SDK manager your code should work.

You might also find post #6 on the link above helpful.

Comment: I'm using revision 19 of the support lib.

Comment: Is it the latest version? Did you try the first method I suggested?

Comment: It is the latest version. I will try your method if nothing else works because I feel that your method WILL work. Why? Because when creating a new project in Android Studio and clicking the checkbox to include ActionBar and Fragments it auto generates something very similar to what you said. Still all of my code uses the method above with ActionBarSherlock, thought this should work with Compat.

Comment: Also, look at post #6 on the link I posted.

Comment: Awesome, can you add that to your answer?

Comment: I have added it to my answer.